# 4 lines of python codes. have no clue why it prints out such output

Tags: python

```
for j in xrange(10,40,5):
    if j % 3 != 0:
        print j
```

OUTPUT:

```
10
20
25
35
```

- I understand that xrange(start, stop, step) and the remainder of 3 is not equal to 0, print j. so So shouldn't it be any number between 10 and 39 that is not divisible by 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for j in xrange(10,40,5):
```

What this loop will generate?

```
10,15,20,25,30,35
```

> Notice, it will generate 10 but not 40 as the first param is inclusive, but second one is exclusive.

Then which of them is not divisible by 3?

```
10,20,25,35
```

Simple as that.

For your added question, see this:

```
for char in "ABC 123":
    print char,
    if not char == '3':
        count += 1
        print count
```

Output:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
  4
1 5
2 6
3
```

I don't think you would get 5

Answer (score 6):

You have a stepsize of 5 in the `xrange`, so only `10 15 20 25 30 35` are tested

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result either (and its badly formatted in a comment). But anyway you should avoid ``not char == '3'``, as it often means ``(not char) == '3'`` instead of ``not (char == '3')``